# Build failed due to invalid symbol

Tags: android, error-handling

[image][image][image: picture shows res/drawables( doesnot contain any "final" image and error shown too][image: added pics for drawable folder][image]I have a few images in my drawables folder and one is called "final". When i run my project, i get the follwing error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
C:\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\aapt.exe package -f -   -no-crunch -I C:\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platforms\android-20\android.jar -M     C:\Users\SHREYA     BISHT\AndroidStudioProjects\staymax\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\SHREYA BISHT\AndroidStudioProjects\staymax\app\build\intermediates\res\debug -A C:\Users\SHREYA BISHT\AndroidStudioProjects\staymax\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\SHREYA BISHT\AndroidStudioProjects\staymax\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\SHREYA BISHT\AndroidStudioProjects\staymax\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_     --debug-mode --custom-package com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax -0 apk
Error Code:
1
Output:
res\drawable-hdpi-v4\final.jpg:0: error: invalid symbol: 'final'
```

Here is what i have already done:
1.Deleted the image and reimported with a different name and made changes in the xml file where i was using the image. Same error.
2. ran invalidate and restart. Same error
3. Ran clean project. Same error.

Please suggest.

activity_main:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/backw"
android:id="@+id/lay">

<TextView android:text="StayMax" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"


    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/sign_in"


    android:id="@+id/btn_first"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="87dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the second page:

```
<TextView android:text="@string/title_signin" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"

 />


<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.33" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/user"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Password :"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign In"
    android:id="@+id/sign"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

This is the third page:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backgr"
tools:context="com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax.hotel_home"

>

<TextView android:text="Welcome to Ayaya"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"

  android:textSize="15dp"

    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.35" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/room_service"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/btn_service"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="104dp"
    android:background="#a1ef7c2d"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hotel_amenities"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/btn_amn"
    android:background="#a1ef7c2d"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_service"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_service"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_service" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/trans"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/btn_trans"
    android:background="#a1ef7c2d"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_amn"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_amn"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

For the next three pages, im trying to set up tab scroll view ( they are sub_menus of sorts)

so first sub menu:
activity_amn_menu.xml

```
<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

second sub_menu:
activity_trans_menu.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax.trans_menu">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

third menu:
activity_service_menu.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax.service_menu"
>


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/dining"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Laundry"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text="House Keeping"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note: This project was running till yesterday and today i decided to incorporate viewpager so they might not run on ur machine now.

Answer (score 0):

**final** is a Java reserved word, you can't name your image like that, choose another name, any other name but don't choose any of reserved words like **static**, **public**, **int**, **exception**, ...etc.

the list of Java reserved words in [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords).

Comment: I realized that and then i deleted the file. It is no longer in my drawables nor am i using a word "final" in my xml. Why the error then?

Comment: @shrbisht go to any of your activities and try to type `R.id.final` and if you find it, So, you must forgot it somewhere else in your app, if you didn't, just restart **eclipse** and **adb** then see if the error still exists

Comment: @muhameed can u explain this a a bit more? whats the role of r.id.final?  R.id.final should be in all java classes?

Comment: @shrbisht No, but the Resources file (/gen/R) that exists in the project contains ids for all the resources in the project, So, if your image "final" still exists in the project it will be exist there, So, if you find it there, that means it's still exists in your project elsewhere and you have to delete it, and if you didn't find it there, that may be because of the leak of flexibility of eclipse and then all you have to do is to restart eclipse and adb

Comment: ok thanks. got it. im using android studio, does it make any difference? i also see that wherever i have "R" in my project , like R.id., its red and says that cannot resolve symbol R.

Comment: @shrbisht ya that's because your project can't be built with the existing error, and the R file generated via build

Comment: @shrbisht also try to put the image "final" again and then rename it inside the project itself(Right Click --> Rename) , and look if there's any errors then, and if any, tell me what's the error written exactly. may be you update your question with it if it's a new error than the old one

Comment: I searched for r.id.final in all my java and xml files. No Match. As per your suggestion, I cant rename the image after adding it to drawables. What i did was rename the image as "backgr" in my desktop and added to drawables. Note that there is no image called "final" and i am still getting the same error.No r.id.final found as well. Please suggest.

Comment: the same error : `res\drawable-hdpi-v4\final.jpg:0: error: invalid symbol: 'final'` ??

Comment: I cant run it right now. I wanted to work with Viewpager and so i installed android repository and support library, made changes in gradle, now gradle wont sync and i cant run the project. Any tips?

Comment: Error Code:
 1
Output:
 res\drawable-hdpi-v4\final.jpg:0: error: invalid symbol: 'final'

Comment: and what you have in **res\drawable-hdpi-v4** ??

Comment: Idk why it gives the location hdpi-v4. In C:\Users\SHREYA BISHT\AndroidStudioProjects\staymax\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi   have 2 images and one ic_launcher that was already present there. Other images are named backgr and backw.

Comment: usually there is a `res` folder outside in the project directory, have a look at the project overall and search for `res\drawable-hdpi-v4`

Comment: i checked res. it contains folders drawable drawable hdpi, drawable mdpi etc and layout,menu, values, values-w820dp. None of these folders contain the final image. Should i start a new project and copy my codes and see what happens? @muhammed

Comment: just open all folders of your project and upload a screenshot of it to look at your project anatomy, making a new project must be your last call as you have to face your problem now in order to not facing it in the future a lot of times

Comment: just added few snips. Is that what u were looking for?

Comment: no, I want a screenshot from the android studio to the anatomy of the app itself(i.e what are the folders and files does it contain)

Comment: @shrbisht search for "drawable.final" in dialog which opens with CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + N. Also search for "final.jpg" with it and inside Windows Explorer.

Comment: @sufian i searched for drawable.final and final.png in android studio with CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + N and also searched in c:/ for any final.png. none found

Comment: @muhammed i am adding snips that contains the part of code that uses that drawable file ( earlier final) and you can also find a snip that shows my java files and res folder. If you need the entire code, i can add codes too

Comment: @shrbisht a thing you could try before going to self-destruction mode - search for "final" in your code and make sure that it isn't in the wrong place.

Comment: why you have two packages with the same name, and are you have a folder called build?

Comment: also post your xml file to test it on my machine

Comment: the other package is unnecessary and i dont know why its there. I am posting my xml codes so u can test on ur machine. Thanks a lot

Comment: @shrbisht well, remove it if you don't need it

Comment: @muhameed i posted all my xml files and i deleted the other project. Ran project again and got the same error

Comment: @sufian , I tried that again. no "final' in any java or xml

Comment: @shrbisht are you noticed that in the last of your second activity you are closing a LinearLayout not exists?

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat there are 2 linear layouts in that activity. I just noticed that the second activity starts with a text view here. Its either a copy-paste mistake or it didnt format very well when i was posting it.

Answer (score 0):

@Muhammed Thank you for all your help today. I resolved the above issue by cleaning the project and then performing a invalidate and restart. I did this earlier today but i guess i didnt perform the clean and restart one after another to see the results.